# react native config: Activity class dose not exists

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-config

I set a file `.env.devdps`

```
APP_NAME=TestDps
```

just use `APP_NAME` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
  ...
  android:label="@string/APP_NAME"
/>
```

In my `android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.testdev"
  manifestPlaceholders = [label: 'testDev']
}
```

and I add a buildTypes `dps`

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    dps {
        initWith debug    
        applicationIdSuffix ".dps" 
        matchingFallbacks =  ['debug']
    }
}
```

Then type command in terminal:
`ENVFILE=.env.devdps npx react-native run-android --variant=dps`

The result shows error `Activity class {com.testdev/com.testdev.MainActivity} does not exist`

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s 46 actionable tasks: 46 executed info Connecting to the development server... info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"... Starting: Intent { cmp=com.testdev/.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.testdev/com.testdev.MainActivity} does not exist.`

How to fix the issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same error, any update on this?

Comment: no, still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java files are under the correct path. For example, if your bundle id is: com.companyname.app they should be under android/app/src/main/java/com/companyname/app.
Also check you have the correct package in your AndroidManifest.xml that should be the same of your bundle id (in this example: com.companyname.app).
Same for package in MainActivity and Mainapplication files.